# GCM Server Key vs Browser Key

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am receiving an `Unauthorized` response from the GCM server on my staging server, but not my development server when using the GCM Server Key. I'm receiving a good response when using the Browser Key on Staging. I would like to know why.

Please note, both server IPs are whitelisted in the Google Development Console. Both server IPs were validated using `curl ipecho.net/plain`.

Here is what I tried:

Development Server:

```
curl --header "Authorization: key=ServerKey" --header Content-Type:"application/json" https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send  -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"ABC\"]}"

Response (good error): {"multicast_id":7259788225649601706,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}
```

Staging Server:

```
curl --header "Authorization: key=ServerKey" --header Content-Type:"application/json" https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send  -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"ABC\"]}"

Response: (Standard Unauthorized 401 HTML)
```

I tried using the Browser Key on the Staging Server, and it worked:

```
curl --header "Authorization: key=BrowserKey" --header Content-Type:"application/json" https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send  -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"ABC\"]}"

Response (good error): {"multicast_id":7259788225649601706,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}
```

Can anyone tell me why?